Rank within group in Polars?
I have a Polars dataframe like so:



c1
c2
c3




a
a
1


a
a
1


a
b
1


a
c
1


d
a
1


d
b
1



I am trying to assign a number to each group of (c2, c3) within c1, so that would look like this:



c1
c2
c3
rank




a
a
1
0


a
a
1
0


a
b
1
1


a
c
1
2


d
a
1
0


d
b
1
1



How do I accomplish this?
I see how to do a global ranking:
df.join(
    df.select(["c1", "c2", "c3"])
    .unique()
    .with_columns(rank=pl.int_range(1, pl.len() + 1),
    on=["c1", "c2", "c3"]
)

but that is a global ranking, not one within the c1 group. I also wonder if it possible to do this with over() instead of the groupby/join pattern.

Shouldn't the rank of the last row be 1?

yes thank you for the fix!

Create a struct of columns c2, c3 using pl.struct("c2", "c3"), compute the dense rank over c1, and then subtract 1 because the ranks start from 1 by default:
pl.struct("c2", "c3").rank("dense").over("c1") - 1

Full code:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "c1": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "d", "d"],
        "c2": ["a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b"],
        "c3": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    }
)

df2 = df.with_columns(rank=pl.struct("c2", "c3").rank("dense").over("c1") - 1)

print(df2)

Output:
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ c1  ┆ c2  ┆ c3  ┆ rank │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ str ┆ i64 ┆ u32  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 0    │
│ a   ┆ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 0    │
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ 1   ┆ 1    │
│ a   ┆ c   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    │
│ d   ┆ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 0    │
│ d   ┆ b   ┆ 1   ┆ 1    │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘

